# Vaadin iFrame is not showing the external content

Tags: iframe, vaadin

I added an iFrame to my Component (Vaadin 14), but the iFrame is empty. Here is my Code, i have also tried it without the DIV but it wont work. There is also no error message, does any one has a hint?

```
    Div div = new Div();
    IFrame iFrame = new IFrame("https://google.de");
    iFrame.setHeight("315px");
    iFrame.setWidth("560px");
    iFrame.getElement().setAttribute("frameborder", "1");
    div.add(iFrame);
    dialogContent.add(div);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at Chrome dev tools and the console, you will see

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.de/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

which means that Google does not allow you to show `www.google.de` in an iframe.

If you change the URL to e.g. http://www.example.com/ and make no other changes, it works.

Comment: Ahhh okay! Great thank you! So my website which i want to show, has this settings also. Great! Now i know where to search. I  wanted to add a confluence page into my App. Hm maybe i have to ask Atlassian how to get it done. Thank you!